# Trying to use functionals to create single-apparition list from given list Racket

Tags: image, functional-programming, racket

I am trying to create a list which only contains the first apparition of each given image , using functionals and a check function .

```
define (check L y )
    (cond
         ((null? L) #t)
         ((equal? (car L) y) #f)
         ((check (cdr L) y ))
    )
)
(check '(1 2 3 4) 2)
(define (remove-duplicates-left L) (foldl check '()  L ) )


(check-exp-part 'a .25 (remove-duplicates-left IMAGES) '(. . . . . . . . .))
```

I get the following error:

*car: contract violation*

*expected : pair?*

*given: (object: image%....)*

In that test case , **Images** is a list of squares/circles and in '(...)' is another list of squares/circles

Comment: How are you expecting `#t` and `#f` to accumulate into a list? Are you looking for `filter`?

Comment: I'm trying to create the 'filtered' list in '() using the on-creation list (which is initialised as '() ) and each element of L is run through that list,to see if it exists . so check says False or True , if it's true, put element in '()  (i want it to act as an accumulator) .

Comment: It feels like the end of the IMAGES sequence is not a list ending?